# Using "rehabilitation" and "physical therapy" as synonyms?

Tags: synonyms, british-english

Are the two terms below interchangeable when addressing injuries?

> - **Rehabilitation** is care that can help you get back, keep, or improve abilities that you need for daily life. These abilities may be physical, mental, and/or cognitive (thinking and learning). You may have lost them because of a disease or injury, or as a side effect from a medical treatment. Rehabilitation can improve your daily life and functioning.

> - **Physical therapy** is a non-invasive discipline that helps individuals develop, maintain and restore maximum body movement and physical function. Physical therapy can help clients recover from an injury, relieve pain, prevent future injury or deal with a chronic condition. It can be applied at any age or stage of life. The ultimate goal of physical therapy is to improve health and quality of life.

May I use *[rehabilitation](https://medlineplus.gov/rehabilitation.html#:%7E:text=Rehabilitation%20is%20care%20that%20can,effect%20from%20a%20medical%20treatment.)* and *[physical therapy](https://www.oleanpt.com/library/4298/WhatIsPhysicalTherapy.html)* interchangeably, as synonyms? Repeating "physical therapy" multiple times in a sentence decreases readability. The context is **physical rehabilitation** after a traumatic injury. Patients rehabilitative care is described by their physical therapy use (this includes relatively similar terms like *occupational therapy* and *exercise therapy*).

Comment: "rehabilitation" has many meanings, including criminal, drug, etc.

Comment: Good point. Or what good practice for such cases. Some kind of statement? I.e. rehabilitation is used as a synonym of physical therapy in this work to avoid repeating the latter?

Comment: Why not use the commonly used abbreviation “PT”? ([Example](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0087987))

Comment: I'm not sure...maybe just referring to it as "therapy" on alternate uses?  Or maybe just PT? How many times do you need to repeat it, actually?

Comment: Basically, each sentence, describing the physical therapy use of these patients, includes it two times: the probability of receiving PT and received amount of PT of those that were included in rehabilitaiton.

Comment: We haven't seen any of your sentences, so...maybe think about using relative clauses or other parenthetical devices in which you can use pronouns to refer to the antecedent?

Comment: If the context makes it clear that you're talking about physical injuries, it will often be obvious that the two terms are equivalent. But rehabilitation can be used more generally.

Comment: Thank you all! We solved this problem with a statement in the text: "Although rehabilitation has a more general meaning than physical therapy, we use these terms interchangeably in this work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rehabilitation" is more general than "physical therapy". Also, rehabilitation is the goal, while physical therapy is the action taken to get that goal. Within a sentence, you can use just "therapy" after the first mention, or just "PT". In a longer passage, you'll have to consider whether it's still clear that "therapy" or "PT" refer to "physical therapy". If you put "PT" in parentheses, this makes it more clear to the reader that they should remember that "PT" means "physical therapy". For instance, "I have physical therapy (PT) tomorrow, and I'm scheduled to continue PT for several weeks".

Comment: All the definitions of "rehabilitation" in my dictionary start with "the action of ...", so it refers to the process, not the goal.

Comment: @Barmar https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rehabilitation gives "the action, process, or result of rehabilitating or of being rehabilitated"